# Summation of Log Probabilities

Tags: python, statistics, probability

I am trying to implement the following:

[image]

where the right part returns a probability between 0 and 1. Regarding the product, the authors of the [respective paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925231217309864) note:

> Due to numerical precision issues with products of probabilities, in
>   our implementation we follow common practice and use summation of log
>   probabilities.

Form what I understand, using the sum of log probabilities helps to prevent underflow. But then I do not get a value between 0 and 1 and the 1- in the formula above does not make sense. What am I missing here? And can I transform the sum of log probabilities back to a value between 0 and 1? When using a large number of probabilities, I still get a very small number, e.g.:

```
log_probability = math.log(0.9) + math.log(0.3) + math.log(0.9) + math.log(1) + math.log(0.9) + math.log(0.3) + math.log(0.3) + math.log(0.3) + math.log(0.3) + math.log(0.3) + math.log(0.3) + math.log(0.3) + math.log(0.3) + math.log(0.3) + math.log(0.3) + math.log(0.3) + math.log(0.3) 
prob = math.exp(log_probability)
```

Where `log_probality=-15.967728003210647` and `prob =1.1622614669999998e-07`.

Thank you, I am really hitting the edge of my understanding of stats here...!

Answer (score 0):

To my mind the thing to be avoided is probabilities becoming zero as floating point numbers, when as real numbers they are not. The strategy is to store, and process, probabilities as their logarithms, and convert back to genuine probabilities when needed.

An example might make this clearer. Suppose we have N models of the data, and we seek to ascribe probabilities to the models. When we process a data instance, we update these probabilities via Bayes rule:

```
P(M,i) is the prior probability ascribed to model i
P(D|i) is the probability of the data, given model i
we update the P(M|i) via
S[i] = P(M,i) * P(D|i)  
T = Sum{ 1<=i<=N | S[i]}
P(M|i) = S[i]/T
```

Problems can arise when we get a sequence of data all of which make one (or more) of the models very unlikely, that is P(D|i) is very much smaller than at least one other model's data probability. In this case it can happen that P(M|i) will become, as a floating point number, zero. Once it does it will stay at zero (because 0 times anything is 0). Even if later the data is such that P(D|i) becomes by far the largest data probability, so that P(M|i) should increase, it won't because it's stuck at 0.

Suppose however we store not P(M,i) but its log l(M,i) say. Now our update becomes

```
s[i] = l(M,i) + log(P(D|i))
t = log( Sum{ 1<=i<=N | exp( s[i]})
l(M|i) = s[i] - t
```

While this is not immune to the problem of spurious 0's, it will avoid it in many cases where the original will succumb.

There is, though, the problem of evaluating:

```
B = log( Sum{ 1<=i<=N | exp( s[i]) })
```

If we evaluate this naively we could end up with 0, if the s[i] are so negative that each exp( s[i]) is 0. In that case the sum will be 0 and the log will be nan.

A simple way to evaluate B is to find the maximum, a say, of the s[i] and then evaluate

B = a + log( Sum{ 1<=i<=N | exp( s[i]-a)})

where we do evaluate the second term by evaluating each exponential. At least one of the s[i]-a is zero, so at least one of the terms in the sum is 1, and all are non negative, so the sum won't 0